# Split the column cell value of location in 3 different columns

Tags: python, excel, pandas

i want to split the location column in 3 different column using python code i have tried basic code and if we have only stae country or on;ly country need to seperate them accordingly

i/p

| Location |
| --- |
| Bengaluru, Karnataka, India |
| Delhi, India |
| India |

Expected output:

| City | State | Country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bengaluru | Karnataka | India |
|  | Delhi | India |
|  |  | India |

```
df = pd.read_excel('filename.xlsx')
df[["City", "State", "Country"]] = df["Location"].str.split(", ", expand=True)
print(df["City"])
df.to_excel('filename.xlsx', index=False)
```

Comment: Text to Columns, separator ",".

Answer (score 0):

Use `str.split` as you did but you have to pad with commas first:

```
pad = pd.Series([','] * len(df), df.index) * (2 - df['Location'].str.count(','))
out = (pad.str.cat(df['Location']).str.split('\s*,\s*', expand=True)
          .set_axis(['City', 'State', 'Country'], axis=1))
print(out)

# Output
        City      State Country
0  Bengaluru  Karnataka   India
1                 Delhi   India
2                         India
```

Details about `pad`:

```
>>> pad
0         # no comma because there are already 3 commas in row 1
1     ,   # one comma because there are already 2 commas in row 2
2    ,,   # two commas because there is no comma in row 3
dtype: object
```

Comment: how to add the changes to existing panda file

Comment: What's wrong with `to_excel`?

Answer (score 0):

If the `Location` column has always the same pattern, you can use :

```
out = pd.DataFrame([[np.nan] * (2 - e.count(",")) + e.split(",")
                    for e in df["Location"]], columns=["City", "State", "Country"])
​
```

Output :

```
print(out)

        City       State Country
0  Bengaluru   Karnataka   India
1        NaN       Delhi   India
2        NaN         NaN   India
```

Comment: how to add to save this in excel ?

Comment: use `out.to_excel("path_to_your_newfile.xslx", index=False)`.

Comment: [AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'count'] it us showing me this error

Comment: Depeding on your needs, use `[... for e in df["Location"].astype(str)]` or  `[... for e in df["Location"].dropna()]`